# switch (v.getId()) where v cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It is just a simple login activity but I need help because I am really stack with the v variable that cannot be resolved in the switch part of my java file. I am new to android development and this is a project that I just started. I am using Eclipse. This is my java file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
    name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    login.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String na=name.getText().toString();
    String pa=pass.getText().toString();


    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        if(na.equals("BoltonLab")&& pa.equals("password")){
            Intent openmainscreen=new Intent ("com.example.handjointstemp.MAINSCREEN");
            startActivity(openmainscreen);
        }

        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        name.setText(" ");
        pass.setText(" ");

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Where do you define variable `v`? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help.

Comment: you made a copy&paste mistake, where is "v" comming from??

Comment: I don't. But I am stack because I don't know how to write that part that checks the login data for approval. I should define v as what?

Comment: Actually yes I am using videos from youtube to make any part of my app right now but this is the way I saw it and it worked. Sorry for any inconvenience. As I said I am completely dummy.

Comment: I changed v.getId to dialog.getId but I got a message: The method getId() is undefined for the type DialogInterface.

Comment: I already tried t replace v with which but the message was "Cannot invoke getId() on the primitive type int"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add this to the declaration of your activity, implementing the clickListener interface.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

it enforces you to override the onClick method with the following signature

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
```

in which you have access to the v.getId() and can compare it to the id of your buttons.

Also , in your onCreate, set onClickListener of the buttons you have to this :

```
login.setOnClickListener(this) ;
cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: This is the beginning of my activity:                                                        public class LoginScreen extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
EditText name;
EditText pass;
Button login;
Button cancel;

Comment: You are overriding the wrong clickListener interface(DialogInterface.OnClickListener), you should override the View.OnClickListener.

Comment: And when I use the public void onClick(View v) I get "The method onClick(View) of type LoginScreen must override or implement a supertype method"

Comment: Pay attention to my first comment and remove the wrong imports

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you so much. It took me lots of hours just for that bug.

Comment: Glad I could help :)